# Play HTML5 videos on tablets

Tags: java, android

I have a working solution to view HTML5 videos in android phones. It does not work at all on android tablets (samsung galaxy tab 2 for example). When I start the video, I can hear audio but the screen is black.

Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/P9ebDKha

Do I have to rewrite all the code? Small mistake?

Answer (score 0):

THis is how i am getting to play a youtube video filling the size of the webview which i have ...

```
               video = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoview);

               String videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/DZi6DEJsOJ0?fs=1&amp;hl=nl_NL";

               video.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
               video.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

               video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
               video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

               Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
               int width = display.getWidth();
           int widthdp = (int) (width / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
               int height = display.getHeight();
          int heightdp = (int) (height / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);


               String widthAndHeight = "width=" + widthdp + "height=" + heightdp;
               String temp = "<object "
              + widthAndHeight
               + ">"
            + "<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>"
          + "<param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>"
          + "</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>"
           + "</param><embed src='"
           + videoPoP
            + "'"
             + " type='application/x-shockwave-flash' style='margin:0;padding:0;'         allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'"
                + widthAndHeight + "></embed></object>";

               video.loadData(temp, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Just a quick hint: Concatenating strings with the ``+`` method is incredibly slow. Use StringBuffer or StringBuilder instead :-)